# Pentaho Business Inteligence Automation

Tags: automation, pentaho

Is there a way to automatically generate reports in Pentaho Business Inteligence?

I'm not speaking about schedule.

I mean something like: if in the database occurred some changes(added some new values, a value of an attribute has been modified...), then generate a report.

If yes, can you recommend some books, tips or online tutorials?

I'm using mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called real time (or live) ETL. If you don't have one-vendor environments (like MS SQL Server, MS SSIS, SharePoint, or Oracle DB with Business Objects, etc..) it's much more easier to implement **near** real time ETL rather than **live** ETL. In that case you just have to set scheduler to run on short period of time - 15 mins for example.

If you want to create live ETL, you have to implement Change Data Capture into your database (if it not exist) and call external process on every change. It creates security treat as well.

You didn't specify what DB you are using, but few years ago I implemented live ETL on MySQL within triggers and MySQL User Defined Function (written in C) which calls some transformations in PDI.

So, perhaps you should start with CDC.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to implement if you are using PostgreSQL.
You just write a user defined function in PL/Python which will connect and login to your Pentaho Server and run the desired `xaction` file.